# Magento 2 - How to retrieve product informations

Tags: product, price, magento2, magento-2.0

I want to use functions like `getName()`, `getPrice()`, etc. of product to retrieve product information in Magento 2.

Can anyone show me how can I achieve that ?

Comment: @JJohn, Is it working below answers. If Yes accept it will useful for other users. If no let me know, so that we can provide solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Magento 2 proposed to use service layer for this.
Try use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getById` method to get product by id

Comment: You should use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getById instead.

Comment: its not recommended to use ProductRepository in Magneto 2

Comment: @WaqarAli, then what is recommended?

Answer (score 15):

On top of others answers, I highly suggest using the **following service contracts methods:**

- `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getById` : to load a product by id
- `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::get` : to load a product by sku

Comment: This is the correct answer, it follows magento directive http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/persistent-entities.html

Answer (score 12):

Magento 2 recommends to use `Factories` for loading all Models. Here is how you should do it:

1. Above your class add this line:

   ```
   use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
   ```
2. Now create class property:

   ```
   protected $productFactory;
   ```
3. In your constructor, add dependency:

   ```
   public function __construct(
      ProductFactory $productFactory
   ) {
      $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
   }
   ```
4. Now load product as below:

   ```
   $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load(<product_id>);
   ```

Comment: there is no class \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory  in Magento 2.1.7

Comment: Most factory classes don't exist in the module. They are generated in var/generation to instantiate classes using the object manager. You should not use factories to load products anyway. Use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface as suggested by others. Or at the very least use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::getById($id)

Comment: Using ProductRepository does not create new objects, such as using a factory does

Answer (score 6):

The more Magento way of achieving this, although it's hard to tell since they most places throughout the core code do it differently is to use the product repository.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
   ProductRepository $productRepository
) {
   $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getMyProduct($productId)
{
    return $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
}
```

Comment: Correct, best and correct answer

Comment: there is Marketplace issue with using productRepository in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

for this you must use below

use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\CollectionFactory`

```
$prod_id = "Your product id goes here";
$om         =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$pdata =   $om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($prod_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have fetch product details using function in product view page like below.

Here Sm/Sawyer is my theme.

```
$_config = $this->helper('Sm\Sawyer\Helper\Data');
$productId = $this->getProduct()->getId();
$name = $this->getProduct()->getName();
$stock1 = $this->getProduct()->getQty();
$price = $this->getProduct()->getPrice();
```

Comment: very bad answer

Comment: Not helpful - just confusing