# Magento2: How to load product by id

Tags: magento2, product

I got the product collection in my custom template using the following snippet:

```
<?php 
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
  $productCollection */
  $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
 /** Apply filters here */

 $productCollection->load();

 foreach ($productCollection as $p)
 {
  echo "<pre>";
  print_R($p->getData());
 }
Here i got array with product id like this

 Array
(
[entity_id] => 1
[attribute_set_id] => 4
[type_id] => virtual
[sku] => Double Corona Natural (box of 25)
[has_options] => 0
[required_options] => 0
[created_at] => 2015-12-23 09:20:38
[updated_at] => 2015-12-23 09:20:38
[is_salable] => 1
)
```

From this entity_id, how can I load products like we did in Magento 1.x?

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
```

Comment: Here is how to do it: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91997/how-to-retrieve-product-information-in-magento-2/113038#113038

Comment: How to write it as a seperate script...cause i get ObjectManager class not found!!

Comment: To load the product in Magento 2 you can use the dependency injection method. Please check this https://www.chandreshvora.com/how-to-load-product-by-id-in-magento-2

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Object method

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

Factory Method

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {


        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

phtml file code

```
$product=$this->getLoadProduct(20);
echo $product->getName();
```

In Magento 2.1

```
<?php
    namespace Test\Module\Block;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
    class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
     {
          protected $productRepository; 
          protected $_storeManager; 

          public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
          ) {
              parent::__construct($context);

              $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
          }
          public function getProduct()
          {

              $productId=1;
              return $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
          }
      }
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-load-product-by-id/)

Comment: Never use object manager directly to load model. Use `factories` instead. See: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/113038/2294

Comment: NOT USE THIS ANSWER, but see new magento directive http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/persistent-entities.html

Comment: @QaisarSatti, $product_title = $product->getName(); returning 500 server error

Comment: @jafarpinjar kindly share your code.

Comment: @QaisarSatti,
  I have configurable product id so can i get only configurable products detail not associated products using product repository ?

Comment: @SanjayGohil share your code what you tried so far

Comment: @QaisarSatti, Thanks for your reply, I have solved it.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd do not work in Magento 2.3

Comment: @Black there were no claim it is working for Magento 2.3. It is an old answer you must respect the it was valid and valid now. I hope some mistake on your end. It is not good behavior to downvote for old answer just because it was not working for you.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, I figured it out. I had to delete the folder `generated/code` and execute `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` after it, now it works. It is a strange magento bug. I edited your question and will upvote after the edit is accepted.

Comment: @Black, unfortunately, your edit is rejected. I think the cache clean was enough.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, no it was not enough, I tried that before. So I also reject the upvote.

Comment: @Black Ok maybe in your case product mode is set. your edit was not rejected by me. it was rejected by other community users.

Comment: Awesome worked for me!