# Magento 2 Get product Review star in phtml

Tags: magento2

I need to show the rating for the products in my custom slider in my home page.

Here im getting just the rating number say: 60 .

How to get the rating stars here in template.

**Featuredproduct\view\frontend\templates\featured_grid.phtml**

```
<?php
                    $_ratingSummary = $block->getRatingSummary($_product->getId());
                    $_reviewCount = $_ratingSummary->getRatingCount();
                    $_ratingSummary =$_ratingSummary->getRatingSummary(); 

                    if($_ratingSummary){ ?>
                    <div class="product-reviews-summary short">
                        <div class="rating-summary">
                            <div title="<?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%" class="rating-result">
                                <span style="width:<?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%"><span><?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%</span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reviews-actions">
                            <?php echo __('('.$_reviewCount.')'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

**Featuredproduct\Block\Featuredproduct.php**

```
protected $_reviewFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    \*Vendor*\Featuredproduct\Model\Resource\Customcollection\Collection $fpmanualCollection,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $datetime,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\History $orderstatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockHelper,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
    //\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Rating\Collection $ratingCollection,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Summary\Collection $ratingCollection,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        array $data = []
)
{
     $this->_coreResource = $resource;
     $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
     $this->_fpmanualCollection = $fpmanualCollection;
     $this->_datetime=$datetime;
     $this->_orderstatus=$orderstatus;
     $this->productCollection=$productCollection;
     $this->ratingCollection=$ratingCollection;
     $this->stockHelper=$stockHelper;

     $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
     $this->_productloader = $_productloader;

    parent::__construct($context,$data);


}



public function getRatingSummary($id)
{ 
    $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($id); // follow the link for this
    $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary();

    return $ratingSummary;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get average rating of product

Comment: yes ,exactly, i need to get the average rating star in my home page product slider, i followed this : https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/How-to-get-rating-summary-in-Magento-2/td-p/40707   But need to know where i have to put this

Comment: You can add it your slider's module or extend that module

Comment: Sorry, You have to do it your self .

Comment: i have updated the question where i need to get the average rating stars, could u suggest  on this

Comment: are you looking for rating in custom block?

Comment: Yes in my custom slider block

Comment: please let me know if you have query

Comment: Have updated now, and modified from your answer, thanks its working now!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Getting Review star in phtml file,

```
   <?php 
        //pass $product object as argument...
        $_ratingSummary = $block->getRatingSummary($product);
        $_reviewCount = $product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
    ?>
    <?php if($_ratingSummary){ ?>
    <div class="product-reviews-summary short">
        <div class="rating-summary">
            <div title="<?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%" class="rating-result">
                <span style="width:<?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%"><span><?php echo (int)$_ratingSummary; ?>%</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reviews-actions">
            <?php echo __('('.$_reviewCount.')'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

**In Block file,**

```
public function getRatingSummary($product)
{
    $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
    return $ratingSummary;
}
```

Comment: can you please help me to get the reviews of the product by customers.

Comment: can you please help me to get the `reviews star` of the product by customers. @Rakesh

Answer (score 2):

In your slider phtml file code just add this function

```
$product = $this->getRatingSummary($passProductIdHere);
var_dump($product);
```

Now in Featuredproduct.php just load that product ([Follow this link for load product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94853/21339)) to get rating for exp :

```
public function getRatingSummary($id)
{ 
    $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($id); // follow the link for this
    $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();

    return $ratingSummary;
}
```

Comment: where is the link?

Comment: @SachinS updated the ans

Comment: Have updated my question @Arunendra, i m getting the rating number now in my block, how to get the average rating star

Answer (score 2):

You have to create and call this method with product ID. It will return rating count of each star. You can calculate the average rating with this result

```
public function getAllStart($pid) {
    $review = $this->_objectReview->getCollection()     //\Magento\Review\Model\Review $reviewFactory (_objectReview)
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status_id', 1)
            ->addEntityFilter('product', $pid)          //$pid = > your current product ID
            ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->addFieldToSelect('review_id')
    ;
    $review->getSelect()->columns('detail.detail_id')->joinInner(
            ['vote' => $review->getTable('rating_option_vote')], 'main_table.review_id = vote.review_id', array('review_value' => 'vote.value')
    );
    $review->getSelect()->order('review_value DESC');
    $review->getSelect()->columns('count(vote.vote_id) as total_vote')->group('review_value');
    for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--) {
        $arrRatings[$i]['value'] = 0;
    }
    foreach ($review as $_result) {
        $arrRatings[$_result['review_value']]['value'] = $_result['total_vote'];
    }
    return $arrRatings;
    }
```