# How to Get product id and Sku By product name magento 2..?

Tags: magento2

How to get Product id and Sku By using the product Name in a phtml file?

Comment: Please search before posting question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94851/magento2-how-to-load-product-by-id

Comment: @Vishwas Bhatnagar if you know the answer post the answer..i have been searching for long and did not find an answer..
i need this in a phtml file..by using the "**product name**"..

Comment: @Vishwas Bhatnagar Can you tel me where is the duplicate here ? he want to get the product by name and not by ID !

Comment: @SUBINCHANDRAN please see Siarhey Uchukhlebau answer , it should work for you . Name is never a unique identifier two products can have same name , so loading product by name might give unreliable results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `.phtml` template you can use only the `ObjectManager` to get desired result:

```
<?php
$productNameHere = 'Aim Analog Watch';
//Get Object Manager Instance
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository */
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
$searchCriteriaBuilder = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder');
$searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('name', $productNameHere)->create();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface[] $items */
$items = $productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
```

or you should do it in the block (not in template, because its recommended as better solution).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I haven't done it before, but I think first you will need to load the product by name and then get the product id and SKU. This can be done via Factory Method:

```
<?php

  protected $product;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product

    ) {
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProduct($name)
    {
        return $this->product->create()->load($name);
    }

}
```

Now call the `getProduct` function in your phtml file like this:

```
$productName = "product_name"; //Product Name
$product=$this->getProduct($productName);

echo $product->getId(); //Get Product ID
```

I hope this would help you.