# convert objectmanager in to factory method in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

Here I don't want to use a object manager.
Below code give me result as i aspect.but I don't want to use a object manager.
I don't known how to convert into factory method.can any one me out.
Here is my code.

```
<?php
 $id= 12; // product id
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->load($id);
 $rating = $objectManager->get("Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory");
 $collection = $rating->create()
    ->addStatusFilter(
        \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
    )->addEntityFilter(
        'product',
         $id
    )->setDateOrder();
   echo "<pre>";
 print_r($collection->getData());
 ?>
```

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94851/magento2-how-to-load-product-by-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your converted code

```
namespace Test\Module\Block;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
      protected $productRepository; 
      protected $_reviewCollection; 

      public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
       \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory   $reviewCollection
      ) {
          parent::__construct($context);

          $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
          $this->_reviewCollection = $reviewCollection;
      }
      public function getProduct()
      {

          $productId=1;
           $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
           $collection = $this->_reviewCollection->create()
              ->addStatusFilter(
                      \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
               )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
              $productId
             )->setDateOrder();
             echo "<pre>";
             print_r($collection->getData());
      }
  }
```