# In Magento 2.2.5 load product by id is not working

Tags: product-collection, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5 load product by id is not working.

I tried the below solutions:

**Sol 1:**

```
$product_id=20;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

**Sol 2:**

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
protected $productFactory;
public function __construct(ProductFactory $productFactory) {
  $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
}
public function getProduct($prodId){
return $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($prodId);
}
```

followed [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94851/magento2-how-to-load-product-by-id)

Update(My Entire Block Code):

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Vendor\Block;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
class Customproduct extends AbstractProduct{
public function getProductDetail($productId) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    return $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
}
```

}

Comment: Check your product id, seem your product id is not available

Comment: @VuTranKien There is only one product available. Its id is 1. Fresh magento2.2.5 Package.

Comment: Can you try the code, if still can't get product : 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById(20);

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the code below for get product detail by id

```
$product_id = 20;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById($product_id);
```

Comment: This code also not working.

Comment: If still not working, you can try reindex store then check code again : php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I tried Even its not working

Comment: Seem this product is out of stock, you can go to admin change this field STORES/CATALOG/Inventory/Stock Options/Display Out of Stock Products = yes then clear cache and check result

Comment: It is in stock only. I have updated my question with my code. Please have a look.

Comment: $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id); you can try by $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82711/discussion-between-saravanan-ds-and-vu-tran-kien).