# Magento 2: Parsing Item information through block

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, collection, variables

I want to create a phtml file and create a dynamic block with that one to put on CMS pages - Take it as product information blocks where i want to display the product name, the price, the URL - nothing more.

Is it possible to make that with something like the standard magento 2 block variable and link that to a phtml file?

I got something like this in mind:

> Magento 2 Block

```
{{widget type="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block" template="widget/static_block/product-info.phtml" product-id="30"}}
```

And then get the information within the `phtml` file via the used product-id on the block variable but I also got no clue how to approach that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do by the following code

> {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blockname" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml" product_id="30"}}

in your phtml file

Now you can get the data by calling:

> $myVar = $block->getData('product_id'); or $this->getData('product_id');

OR

> $myVar = $block->getProductId();

Comment: Works! Thank you :)
Do you also know how i can get the "incl. xx% VAT" text via this method ? like `$product->getProductTax();` ?

Comment: I think you can't get product tax directly in phtml file from cms block/page, but you can get it via phtml file to call function in block check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94853/55928)