# Set current product for custom block in category list

Tags: magento2, product-list, custom-block

I have added a custom block in each product item, in category list page:

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">

                        <block class="Mymodules\Auction\Block\Product\CustomList\AuctionList" name="auction.product.customlist" as="auction-product-customlist" template="Mymodules_Auction::product/list/auction_list.phtml" />

                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

**Mymodules/Auction/Block/Product/CustomList/AuctionList.php**

```
<?php
namespace Mymodules\Auction\Block\Product\CustomList;

class AuctionList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {       
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {       
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

How can I get current product object?

Function getCurrentProduct() above is not working.

Is it possible to pass current product object as an **argument** in `catalog_category_view.xml`?

Comment: Hi, what do you want to display in this block? Because you can simply override ```lst.phtml``` file from ```Magento_Catalog``` and than in foreach loop you will have access to current product.

Comment: I want to load custom module data, it's not possible just by working on list.pthml file

Comment: So if you call your block in list.phtml file, you can try to load product by Id.
this should help: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94851/magento2-how-to-load-product-by-id

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but worth an anwser to help someone else. You basically wanted to set data for you custom block within list.phtml so building on your module you could have potentially done it like this. Hopefully you managed to figure it out.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Category\Display")->setTemplate("VENDOR_MODULE::category/auction.phtml")->setData("product", $_product)->toHtml(); ?>
```