# exclude some other product in the cart from receiving discount

Tags: event-observer, product-attribute, shopping-cart-price-rules, helper

How to get product value ( product price) if attribute "logitech" is set to yes [attribute is Boolean].

I'm new here, still learning magneto. below code, calculate all items in the cart but i attribute logitech product to be excluded from getting discount

```
class Discount extends Calculation
{
    /**
     * @param Quote $quote
     * @param ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param Total $total
     *
     * @return $this|Calculation
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws Zend_Serializer_Exception
     */
    public function collect(
        Quote $quote,
        ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();

        if (!$items || !$this->canCalculate($quote->getStoreId(), true) || $quote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
            $this->resetAffiliate($quote);

            return $this;
        }

        $itemFields = ['affiliate_discount_amount', 'base_affiliate_discount_amount'];
        $this->resetAffiliateData(
            $items,
            $quote,
            array_merge($itemFields, ['affiliate_discount_shipping_amount', 'affiliate_base_discount_shipping_amount']),
            $itemFields
        );
        $account            = $this->registry->registry('mp_affiliate_account');
        $isBreakCampaign    = false;
        $affiliateKey       = $this->getAffiliateKey(); // if no cookie then first order key
        $affSource          = $this->getAffiliateSourceFromCookie(self::AFFILIATE_COOKIE_SOURCE_NAME);
        $campaignCouponCode = null;

        if ($affSource === 'coupon') {
            $affCodeWithPrefix = explode('-', $affiliateKey);
            if (count($affCodeWithPrefix) === 2) {
                $campaignCouponCode = $affCodeWithPrefix[1];
            } else {
                return $this;
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->getAvailableCampaign($account, $campaignCouponCode) as $campaign) {
            $isCalculateTax      = $campaign->getApplyDiscountOnTax();
            $isCalculateShipping = $campaign->getApplyToShipping();
            $totalCart           = $this->getTotalOnCart($items, $quote, $isCalculateShipping, $isCalculateTax, false);

            if ($totalCart getDiscountOnCampaign($campaign, $totalCart);
            if ($quote->getBaseAffiliateDiscountAmount() + $totalDiscount > $totalCart) {
                $totalDiscount   = $totalCart - $quote->getBaseAffiliateDiscountAmount();
                $isBreakCampaign = true;
            }
            $baseDiscount = $discount = 0;

            if ($totalDiscount) {
                $lastItem = null;
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isChildrenCalculated()) {
                        /** @var Item $child */
                        foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                            $this->calculateItemDiscount(
                                $child,
                                $totalCart,
                                $totalDiscount,
                                $baseDiscount,
                                $discount,
                                $isCalculateTax,
                                $lastItem
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->calculateItemDiscount(
                            $item,
                            $totalCart,
                            $totalDiscount,
                            $baseDiscount,
                            $discount,
                            $isCalculateTax,
                            $lastItem
                        );
                    }
                }

                if ($campaign->getApplyToShipping()) {
                    $shippingBaseDiscount = $totalDiscount - $baseDiscount;
                    $shippingDiscount     = $this->priceCurrency->convert($shippingBaseDiscount);
                    $quote->setAffiliateDiscountShippingAmount(
                        $quote->getAffiliateDiscountShippingAmount() + $shippingDiscount
                    );
                    $quote->setBaseAffiliateDiscountShippingAmount(
                        $shippingBaseDiscount
                    );
                    $baseDiscount += $shippingBaseDiscount;
                    $discount     += $shippingDiscount;
                } elseif ($lastItem && $totalDiscount > $baseDiscount) {
                    $lastItemBaseDiscount = $totalDiscount - $baseDiscount;
                    $lastItemDiscount     = $this->priceCurrency->convert($lastItemBaseDiscount);
                    $lastItem->setBaseAffiliateDiscountAmount(
                        $item->getBaseAffiliateDiscountAmount() + $lastItemBaseDiscount
                    )->setAffiliateDiscountAmount($item->getAffiliateDiscountAmount() + $lastItemDiscount);
                    $baseDiscount += $lastItemBaseDiscount;
                    $discount     += $lastItemDiscount;
                }

                $quote->setAffiliateDiscountAmount($quote->getAffiliateDiscountAmount() + $discount);
                $quote->setBaseAffiliateDiscountAmount($quote->getBaseAffiliateDiscountAmount() + $baseDiscount);
                $baseGrandTotal = $total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseDiscount;
                $grandTotal     = $total->getGrandTotal() - $discount;
                if ($grandTotal setAffiliateKey($this->getAffiliateKeyFromCookie());
                $total->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal);
                $total->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal);
                $quote->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
                $quote->save();

                if ($isBreakCampaign) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $item
     * @param $total
     * @param $totalDiscount
     * @param $baseDiscount
     * @param $discount
     * @param $isCalculateTax
     * @param $lastItem
     */
    public function calculateItemDiscount(
        $item,
        $total,
        $totalDiscount,
        &$baseDiscount,
        &$discount,
        $isCalculateTax,
        &$lastItem
    ) {
        $itemBaseDiscount = ($this->getItemTotalForDiscount($item, $isCalculateTax, false) / $total) * $totalDiscount;
        $itemBaseDiscount = $this->round($itemBaseDiscount, 'base');
        $itemDiscount     = $this->convertPrice($itemBaseDiscount, false, false, $item->getStoreId());
        $itemDiscount     = $this->round($itemDiscount);
        $item->setBaseAffiliateDiscountAmount($item->getBaseAffiliateDiscountAmount() + $itemBaseDiscount)
            ->setAffiliateDiscountAmount($item->getAffiliateDiscountAmount() + $itemDiscount);
        $baseDiscount += $itemBaseDiscount;
        $discount     += $itemDiscount;
        $lastItem     = $item;

    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94853/99520

Comment: Thanks for the link @RutvikMonpara but it not working for me. i need to get product price if attribute logitech is set to yes

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    namespace Test\Module\Helper;

    use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

    class Product extends AbstractHelper
     {
          protected $productRepository; 

          public function __construct(
            ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
          ) {
              $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
          }

          public function getProduct($productId=1)
          {
              $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
              $logitech = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('logitech')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
              if($logitech){
                    return $product;
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: this code worked but please help with above problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is still not clear, but i want to suggest one thing about processing product attributes in cart. Boolean value should be stored as 1 or 0/null.

If you want to load your attribute for quote you may create following rule

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/catalog_attributes.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="logitech"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

After this you can use this attribute with Quote Item instance. Example:

```
    // example with iterate quote
    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $quoteItem) {
        $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
        if ($product->getData('logitech') === '1') {
            // custom logic here
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have edited my question sorry for that and thank you for the suggestion